# Passing struct to a function

Tags: c++, c, struct, binary

---

### *This works:*

```
struct client {
    string address;
    int toPay;
    int id;
};

int main() {
    struct client clients[10];
    ...
    file.read( (char*)&clients, sizeof (clients) );
}
```

---

What I want to do, is do those things inside of a function.

But how would I have to pass the struct to the function?

If I pass it likes this, read doesn't work:

```
void newFunction ( struct client *clients_t) {
    ...
    file.read( (char*)&clients_t, sizeof (clients_t) );
}
```

Comment: just change your parameter to struct client& clients_t

Comment: Could you provide the signature of file.read

Comment: What is that "string" you use? Is it std::string?

Comment: As an aside, you really should not be simply dumping structs into a file.  You ought to be constructing serialization and deserialization methods for your struct.  Explicitly converting to and from `char` arrays in a controlled fashion.

Comment: You shouldn't leave out `using namespace std;`, in fact, you really shouldn't even be `using namespace std;`.  You should probably just type out those 5 extra chars. `std::` isn't that long, and it makes your code much clearer, and you won't have to troubleshoot really weird and random compile time or run time errors, when you just happen to use one of the function names that happens to appear within `std` unknowingly.

Comment: I meant that I left it out of this post intentionally because it's obvious that I'd type if it were for real. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not going to work, because the `string` data is not embedded into the `struct`. Instead, it has a couple of pointers to the string content. That is why `file.read( (char*)&clients...)` is not going to produce a valid result: the `string` will point to the place where a saved `string` once pointed, but it would no longer represent the data of interest.

If you would like to serialize the data like that, embed an entire `char` array in the `struct`, with the obvious limitation that there would be a cap on the number of characters and some wasted space.

Comment: Finally someone who says it.

Comment: Well, I'll check yours then. :p

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `&` in the `file.read()` call.

So:

```
file.read((char *)clients_t, sizeof(*clients_t) * 10 );
```

You are passing the address of the pointer itself, but what you want is the address of the structure array, and to pass its correct size.

However, while that makes the `read` technically valid, it won't create `string` objects for you, so that fragment would only work in the unusual case that you had written out the references to your own objects earlier in the lifetime of that one process.

As a learning experience, reading and writing binary data is a great idea.

IRL, though, usually you don't want to do it at all, except perhaps via a DBMS. It's hard to debug and can be architecture-specific by exposing the byte order. Think YAML, XML, or CSV instead.

Comment: I figured that I should remove the ampersand, but I didn't think that I'd need to put an asterisk after sizeof.

>_<

I must improve my pointer-knowledge asap.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply create an object of struct in the function.
It will work that way too.
and then you can access the members of the struct in that function using the object you created.

Answer (score 1):

`&clients_t` is a pointer to a pointer.
`clients_t` is a pointer which is what is required.

```
void newFunction ( struct client *clients_t) {
    ...
    file.read( (char*)clients_t, sizeof (clients_t) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A struct is just an object, so you treat it just as you would treat other object.

```
void Foo(client& ClientObj)
{
   //anything written in here directly effects the client object you passed
}
```

notice you need to pass by reference, if not you would only pass a copy of the object.

```
//in main
client CObj;
Foo(CObj);
```